# Botones y enlaces en web version movil

Tags: javascript, html, css

Porque los enlaces / botones se ven asi en la versión movil de mi web? Se ve con ese azul, y tapa el efecto que si hace en la version de escritorio, saben como se puede sacar y se vea como en la web normal?

Por ejemplo en StackOverflow tambien tiene este efecto en la versión movil.
Aca dejo una foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y dejo un boton de ejemplo, aunque creería que es en los `<a href="..."></a>`

```
<div class="byline jump-link">
   <a class="flat-button ripple" href="enlace.com" title=" Enlace">
     <div class="splash-wrapper">
       <span class="splash" style="height: 81.6875px; width: 81.6875px; left: 14.1562px; top: -12.8438px;"></span>
     </div>
Leer más
</a>
</div>
```

Agrego: Acabo de ver que en todos los que toma este estilo tiene esto:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

No se si sea esto lo que opaca el estilo

Comment: cuál es el estilo aplicado al botón que se muestra distinto? y en qué navegador/es sucede este cambio?

Comment: Es el mismo estilo, y es en todos los navegadores, mira, entra a stackoverflow desde el celular, y da clic en cualquier lado y vas a ver.

Comment: gracias por la no ayuda, de verdad, vaya que ayudan

Comment: Es difícil ayudarte si no se entiende bien el problema, te preguntaba cuál es el estilo que vos aplicaste al botón, o cómo esperás vos que se vea, para buscar la diferencia respecto de cómo se ve (css). En stackoverflow yo veo los botones con el mismo estilo en escritorio y mobile, entonces no puedo saber cuál es exactamente el problema que estás experimentando. Cuantos más detalles expliques, más posibilidades hay de que alguien en la comunidad te pueda ayudar

Comment: Edité el tema hace unos dias. Y los estilos no es el problema, el problema es cuando le das clic, fijate, dale clic y vas a ver el el celular como el icono se pone azul como en la foto.